# how to install Boost (for c++) on Ubuntu for c++

Tags: ubuntu, installation, boost

One 3rd party library I need to build requires a higher version boost than our system /usr/include/boost. So I downloaded the latest boost package, and cd tools/build, then run following two commands:

1. ./boostrap.sh
2. ./b2 install --prefix="my_home_directory"

After this, I found two the following two directories are "installed" under my home directory:
share/b2
bin/b2

I don't see any include (for boost header files) and lib (for boost libraries) being installed there. Plus, why there is a need to "build" boost, as they are all implemented in header files (to my knowledges).

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Those look like the commands to install `Boost.Build` rather than `boost` itself.  Instead try `./bootstrap.sh --prefix="my_home_directory"` followed by `./b2 install` .

Comment: GM, just tried it, no luck, when I tried ./b2 install , it is trying to create directory /usr/local/share/b2 , and of course, it failed due to permission. I ran both boostrap.sh and b2 from boost_1_81_0/tools/build/ . Is it the right place to run those two commands. Something must be terribly wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: I figured out my silly mistake. I ran those two commands at a wrong directory. I should I have run them under the top directory.